# Grouping points within counties and symbolizing their data as pie charts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, point-in-polygon, chart, grouping

I need to combine/categorize points within different polygons while retaining some of their values. I've made up a scenario to try and simplify my problem.

The layers I have to work with are a point file with individuals id's and their favorite numbers and a polygon file with county borders and names.

individual 1's favorite number is 14

Individual 2's favorite number is 96

Individual 3's favorite number is 53

individuals 1 and 2 live in County X while Individual 3 lives in County Y.

I want to symbolize each county with a pie diagram showing the % individuals with their favorite numbers.
County x would have 50% of people liking 14 and 50% liking 96.

I've made some progress but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

I used ''Join attributes by location'' for each point their respective county in the attribute table.

And I've managed to quantify the favorite numbers using the following expression

```
count("favourite", group_by:= "county", filter:="favourite"='14')
```

So my attribute table ends up with this:

```
  Favorite number 14    Favorite number 96     
  1                     1
```

So I already have something I could make pie charts out of but the problem is I have lots of counties and lots of favorite numbers. Writing such an expression for each favorite number doesn't seem like a very elegant way to go about it. I don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated!

PS My actual point data holds more information than `"favorite number"`, if possible I would like to retain this but it's not a requirement.